# How to link to a subfolder of a share?

Tags: windows, network-shares, smb, cifs, unc

On my Windows XP server, a folder called `Share2` is shared. It contains a subfolder called `folder3`.
The guest account is protected by a password, which means network users have to type the guest password to access it.

When a user types `\\server\Share2` in his file explorer, he is prompted for a password.
When a user types `\\server\Share2\folder3` in his file explorer, an error appears. He is not even prompted for a password.

This is problematic because I want to link to this particular folder.
How can I link to `folder3`?

---

Notes:
- Both Desktop shortcuts and HTML links in IE7/8 give an error if I link to `folder3`, but work if I just link to `Share2`.
- Using the `file://` syntax instead of the `\\` syntax leads to the same results.
- Password setting per http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-password-protect-a-shared-folder
- Not using "Simple File Sharing"
- The error message is が見つかりません。綴りを確認してもう一度実行する which means "could not find it. check the path and try again". No English Windows around to try, sorry! It is easy to reproduce the problem though, so can anyone post the English error message for the sake of searchability? Thanks!

Comment: if the use browses to \\server\Share2 and then tries to open folder 3, are they able to?

Comment: XP Home with Simple File Sharing turned on?

Comment: @mh: XP Pro, no using "Simple Sharing".
@Sam: Yes, if the user browses to \\server\Share2 he can open folder3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been my experience as well. I believe it's not a default Windows' behavior to try to authenticate when you link directly to the sub-folder. You have to have authenticated **before** you try to get to the sub, and if that's not been done during this "session", then Windows won't prompt for a password, as you say, and just fails.

Is it so bad to have people link to share first?

Could you also share `folder3`? Then people would be prompted.

Sorry, I know this isn't ideal. Tell MS you want this fixed.  :)

Comment: Accepting answer for confirming what my suspicion: it is a Microsoft bug.  
How can they let this happen? Bug introduced in IE7, and they did not fix it for IE8...

I am contributing to the open-source Alfresco software. Alfresco shows a company's files on an intranet website. This website contains CIFS links to each folder and file. And of course most folders are sub-folders. Requiring the user to first open the root folder is not ideal, users will get angry :-(

Sharing every single subfolder means authentication would appear for every folder the user opens, not ideal either :-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `\\server\Share2\Share3$` ?

Comment: I just tried it. Same result.